# hadoop large data set

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

What makes data sets large? Will it be a collection of files or a file? If I upload files into hdfs then name node keeps three important meta information like name of file, total blocks and size of file and each information contains 150 bytes which becomes 450 bytes. if we upload plenty of file of same data then name node memory has to be increased.

I am confused here. Whether one file should be bigger like 1 TB  or  collection of files will be?

I have seen plenty of data sets on internet but never found one file could be even 200 GB. There are files which make 200 GB size.
Can you please explain about it?

Comment: Please clarify. What is the problem? Or are you just asking "what kind of data sets could be that large"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small files are problem for hadoop processing read from [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/)

**Problems with small files and HDFS**

A small file is one which is significantly smaller than the HDFS block size (default 64MB). If you’re storing small files, then you probably have lots of them (otherwise you wouldn’t turn to Hadoop), and the problem is that HDFS can’t handle lots of files.

Every file, directory and block in HDFS is represented as an object in the namenode’s memory, each of which occupies 150 bytes, as a rule of thumb. So 10 million files, each using a block, would use about 3 gigabytes of memory. Scaling up much beyond this level is a problem with current hardware. Certainly a billion files is not feasible.

**Problems with small files and MapReduce**

Map tasks usually process a block of input at a time (using the default FileInputFormat). If the file is very small and there are a lot of them, then each map task processes very little input, and there are a lot more map tasks, each of which imposes extra bookkeeping overhead. Compare a 1GB file broken into 16 64MB blocks, and 10,000 or so 100KB files. The 10,000 files use one map each, and the job time can be tens or hundreds of times slower than the equivalent one with a single input file.

Reference:
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/

Hope that helps

Comment: I have 450 GB log files. One file size is 800 MB. Will 800 MB be considered large data set or 450 GB ( which is the collection of files) ? Or I have to make one file of 450 GB to copy onto Hadoop?

Comment: As far as I know  800MB file should be big enough to process.

Comment: according to my experience, I have not seen a file which can have size in GB (especially log or csv) file. I have to copy 56 files onto hadoop? Will it be good?